# Enabling main content take full width on mobile screen

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile, responsive

I had searched forum for answers but didnt find one that could be applied to my question. I want that my .main-content ( article text and images ) take up full width on mobile screen without .sidebar and .ad showing off.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
            <title>Demo</title>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
            <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="normalize.css">
    </head> 
    <body>
            <div class="wrapper">   
                <header class="main-head">The Header</header>
                <nav class="main-nav">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="index.html">Nav 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="nav2.html">Nav 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="nav3.html">Nav 3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
                <article class="content">
                            <h1 class="h1">Main article area</h1>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In rhoncus neque mi, suscipit molestie tellus sollicitudin eu. Praesent bibendum lorem at lacus luctus dignissim. Phasellus non volutpat est. Duis sed venenatis arcu, sed accumsan elit. Morbi luctus odio in pellentesque rutrum. Nunc suscipit enim tortor, vel mattis ligula semper a. Mauris at lacinia leo. Aenean luctus elit eget dolor dignissim cursus. Aliquam vulputate ut tellus sed volutpat.
                            Nam consequat arcu id nunc gravida dictum. Mauris mattis vitae metus nec commodo. Vestibulum malesuada mattis ex, sit amet aliquam augue placerat eget. Fusce finibus ullamcorper tortor, vel tempus diam cursus et. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Etiam sit amet turpis diam. In semper lacinia nunc. Fusce risus sapien, sodales vitae pellentesque in, luctus id libero. Nunc ante velit, volutpat vitae dignissim vel, maximus eu lorem. Donec non fermentum nisl. Praesent vitae accumsan nisi, eu porta diam.</p>
                            <br>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In rhoncus neque mi, suscipit molestie tellus sollicitudin eu. Praesent bibendum lorem at lacus luctus dignissim. Phasellus non volutpat est. Duis sed venenatis arcu, sed accumsan elit. Morbi luctus odio in pellentesque rutrum. Nunc suscipit enim tortor, vel mattis ligula semper a. Mauris at lacinia leo. Aenean luctus elit eget dolor dignissim cursus. Aliquam vulputate ut tellus sed volutpat.
                            Nam consequat arcu id nunc gravida dictum. Mauris mattis vitae metus nec commodo. Vestibulum malesuada mattis ex, sit amet aliquam augue placerat eget. Fusce finibus ullamcorper tortor, vel tempus diam cursus et. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Etiam sit amet turpis diam. In semper lacinia nunc. Fusce risus sapien, sodales vitae pellentesque in, luctus id libero. Nunc ante velit, volutpat vitae dignissim vel, maximus eu lorem. Donec non fermentum nisl. Praesent vitae accumsan nisi, eu porta diam.</p>
                            <img src="image.webp" alt="Dummy" class="responsive">
                </article>
                <aside class="side">Sidebar</aside>
                <div class="ad">Advertising</div>
                <footer class="main-footer">The footer</footer>
            </div>       
    </body>
</html>
```

```css
.wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 0;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 4fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: auto auto 1fr auto;
    height: 100vh;
    grid-template-areas: 
      "header  header    header"
      "nav     nav       nav"
      "sidebar article   ad"
      "footer  footer    footer";
}
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    font-size: 100%;
}
.main-head {
    grid-area: header;
    background-color: teal;
    background-color: red !important;
}
.content {
    grid-area: article;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: orange;
    background-color: white !important;
}
.main-nav {
    grid-area: nav;
    background-color: lightblue;
    background-color: red !important;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    position: sticky;
    z-index: 9999; 
}
.side {
    grid-area: sidebar;
    background-color: tomato;
    background-color: white !important;
}
.ad {
    grid-area: ad;
    background-color: lightgreen;
    background-color: white !important;
}
.main-footer {
    grid-area: footer;
    background-color: ghostwhite;
}
li {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 1rem;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}
ul { 
    display: flex;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    }
.main-head, .content, .side, .ad, .main-footer {
    padding: 1rem;
}
.responsive {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
.h1 {
    font-size: 48px;
}
a:hover {
    color: white;
}
/* Media Queries: Tablet Landscape */
@media screen and (max-width: 1060px) {
    #primary { width:67%; }
    #secondary { width:30%; margin-left:3%;}  
}
/* Media Queries: Tabled Portrait */
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    #primary { width:100%; }
    #secondary { width:100%; margin:0; border:none; }
}
```

Thank you in advance and feel free to suggest if there is something wrong with my code.

Comment: Are you using android WebView  ? If yes can you post the image of the mobile screen  and how do you lay out the WebView widget

Comment: I dont use WebView but I had deployed my site using Netlify so you can take a look. https://demosite091.netlify.com/

Comment: You need to deploy it on real mobile phone or a mobile simulator to see how the page shows.

Comment: Does chrome developer tool qualify like device simulator? If yes, I had used that already but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

The article is not taking full width because you have applied display: grid in .wrapper class. The CSS Grid Layout Module offers a grid-based layout system, with rows and columns. To make your article in full width, apply .wrapper{display:block} in responsive.  Hope this help!

`@media screen and (max-width: 767px){
   .wrapper{display: block;}
}`

Comment: Can you be more specific where do I have to put that line of code because after applying it my content was going out of borders and sidebar was moved beneath when viewed on mobile. Thanks.

Comment: You have to add this CSS after  @media screen and (max-width: 768px) media query. and can  I know where do you want to place sidebar in mobile view?